# UnboundLocalError: Referenced before assignment local variable 'emoji_count'

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, discord, discord.py

Hi I had this niggling issue with a cog (bot module) on writing and I keep getting an `UnboundLocalError: Referenced before assignment` I'm aware this is a very common issue however I'm not seeing the issue.

The module works but every time a post is reacted to with a star it throws off this error in the console.

The error is:

`starboard.py", line 22, in on_reaction_add
    if emoji_count > 0: #if 0 then 1 counts
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'emoji_count' referenced before assignment`

The area of more specific I'm looking at is:

```
async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):

    for guild in self.bot.guilds:
        chan = get(guild.channels, name="starboard")
        if chan:
            if reaction.message.author == user:
                return
            if reaction.emoji == '⭐' or reaction.emoji == '':
                if not chan:
                    return
                emoji_count = reaction.message.reactions[0].count
                msg = f"{reaction.message.author.mention} your post was posted to starboard." 
                em = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)))
                display = f"""{reaction.message.content}"""
                em.description = display
                em.set_author(name=reaction.message.author.name, icon_url=reaction.message.author.avatar_url)
                em.set_footer(text=f"Posted in: #{chan.name}")
                em.timestamp = dt.datetime.utcnow()
            try:
                img_url = reaction.message.attachments[0].url
            except IndexError:
                img_url = None
            if not img_url:
                try:
                    img_url = reaction.message.embeds[0].url
                except IndexError:
                    img_url = None
            if img_url:
                em.set_image(url=str(img_url))
            if emoji_count > 0: #if 0 then 1 counts
                if not chan:
                    return
                await chan.send(msg)
                await chan.send(embed=em)
```

If anyone can tell me whats going on here and where I'm going wrong I'd much appreciated it.

Comment: If the reaction is not one of the stars, then `emoji_count` will not have a value in that `if`.  Also you can get the guild a reaction is from via `reaction.message.guild`.  You don't need to loop through all the guilds you know about.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little bit confused is it possible you could give me an example of this.

Comment: If i have `if False: x = 1` in  my code, and later I try `print(x)`  what do you think is going to happen?

Comment: How would I get around this error or how do I pass the number. `#if 0 then 1 counts`  is the default value of the  reactions added to the message. 0 value I think means if the message has `0 emoji_count` (No emojis) then 1 star reaction will add to the message starboard. I apologise I'm quite new to py.

Answer (score 0):

When your if statement condition in `if reaction.emoji == '⭐' or reaction.emoji == '':` doesn't return `True` ,  `emoji_count`  won't get initialized
(`emoji_count = reaction.message.reactions[0].count`)
So when you try to use it a couple of lines underneath in `if emoji_count > 0:` it causes
 `local variable 'emoji_count' referenced before assignment`, which is exactly what it says, python not being able to find your variable's initialization anywhere in the code that ran

Comment: I'm still having some trouble in understanding how I'm supposed to return True with `if reaction.emoji == '⭐' or reaction.emoji == '':` all I can think of is the `return True` Boolean but as you stated it will only reference `emoji_count`.

Comment: You have to initialize `emoji_count `  beforehand, put it at the top as something like `emoji_count = 0`

Comment: It's fixed the error but I have have bumped in to another strange one. I placed `emoji_count = 0` at the top and changed `if emoji_count > 2:` if another emojis other than star `if reaction.emoji == '⭐' or reaction.emoji == '':` are used it won't run. I'm assuming it's this line `emoji_count = reaction.message.reactions[0].count` thats causing the issue.

Comment: The same way you have to initialize your `emoji_count` you also have to initialize your `em = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)))` somewhere at the top since if the emojis aren't stars it won't get initialized and this line `if img_url:
                em.set_image(url=str(img_url))` won't work (will throw the same error). I'm not sure what you mean by "it won't run" since that seems to be what you want (to only run if user inputs one of the stars). You might try to change `emoji_count = reaction.message.reactions[0].count`to `emoji_count = reaction.count`

Answer (score -1):

I think what is being said here is the following:

```
  if emoji_count >= 2 : 
                if not chan:
                    return True
```

Comment: This will also attempt to reference `emoji_count` before assigning it a value

Answer (score -2):

As said in the previous answers it should be

`if reaction.emoji == '⭐' or reaction.emoji == '' is True:`

Comment: `reaction.emoji == '' is True` will be evaluated as `reaction.emoji ==( '' is True)`, which is always going to be false.